# Unable to share authentication cookie with new dotnet core web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, owin

**New question**

Update: since this started with some general challenges and has since zeroed in on a more specific issue I've [re-posted as a new question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66904838/shared-session-cookie-is-not-being-recognised-by-authentication-scheme).

---

I have been following [Microsoft's advice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#share-authentication-cookies-without-aspnet-core-identity) for sharing an authentication cookie issued by an ASP.NET web app with a separate dotnet core web app running on the same domain. Unfortunately the dotnet core app is not unprotecting the cookie as expected and I'm struggling to diagnose why.

I'll try to simplify what I've done. Before I do I should point out that both apps will run under the same path - let's call it mydomain.com/path - so the auth cookie will be scoped to that path. There's a lot of additional complexity because I'm actually trying to wire this into an old OIDC library, but I think the main issue I'm having is on the other side where I have a fairly lightweight dotnet core app trying to use the same session.

First, in my original .NET app (it's 4.7.2) I'm creating a new data protector using the `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Interop` library:

```
var appName = "<my-app-name>";

var encryptionSettings = new AuthenticatedEncryptionSettings()
{
    EncryptionAlgorithm = EncryptionAlgorithm.AES_256_CBC,
    ValidationAlgorithm = ValidationAlgorithm.HMACSHA256
};

var interopProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(
    new DirectoryInfo(keyRingSharePath),
    builder =>
    {
        builder.SetApplicationName(appName);
        builder.SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(365 * 20));
        builder.UseCryptographicAlgorithms(encryptionSettings);

        if (!generateNewKey)
        {
            builder.DisableAutomaticKeyGeneration();
        }
    });

return new DataProtectorShim(
    interopProvider.CreateProtector(
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware",
        appName,
        "v2"));
```

Note that `<my-app-name>` is also the name of the cookie, as set in the `CookieAuthenticationOptions`.

`keyRingSharePath` is for now just a local path on my PC. The first time I run this I have `generateNewKey` set to `true` to ensure a new key is generated at this path. Thereafter I leave this `false` to ensure that key is re-used.

I also assign the ticket data format using this data protector as per the docs: `new TicketDataFormat(dataProtector)`.

This works as expected in that authentication still works and I can even verify the data protection by using an instance of the `TicketDataFormat` created above and calling its `Unprotect` method with the auth cookie value and getting a `ClaimsIdentity` back.

Next I've created a simple dotnet core app which runs on the same domain as the above app. In the `Startup` I've added this:

```
var primaryAuthenticationType = "<my-app-name>";
var cookieName = primaryAuthenticationType;

services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(keyRingSharePath))
    .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(365 * 20))
    .DisableAutomaticKeyGeneration()
    .UseCryptographicAlgorithms(new AuthenticatedEncryptorConfiguration()
    {
        EncryptionAlgorithm = EncryptionAlgorithm.AES_256_CBC,
        ValidationAlgorithm = ValidationAlgorithm.HMACSHA256
    })
    .SetApplicationName(primaryAuthenticationType);

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
    options.Cookie.Name = cookieName;
    options.Cookie.Path = "/path";
});
```

Obviously `keyRingSharePath` holds the same value as in the ASP.NET app. I also have the following in the `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup`:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Having signed in using the ASP.NET app I then switch to my dotnet core app. But unfortunately when debugging any controller with a route under `/path` I find that `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is `false`.

I've also tried unprotecting the cookie manually like this, using an injected instance of `IDataProtectionProvider`:

```
var protector = protectionProvider.CreateProtector(
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware",
    "<my-app-name>",
    "v2");

var ticketDataFormat = new TicketDataFormat(dataProtector);

var ticket = ticketDataFormat.Unprotect("<auth-cookie-value>");

return ticket?.Principal;
```

However, `ticket` is assigned null and I can't find any way to debug why it won't unprotect the cookie value. As far as I can tell this should use the same logic that my ASP.NET app used when I confirmed that I could unprotect that cookie.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

---

**UPDATE 1**

I've been playing around a bit more by trying to deconstruct the code that unprotects the cookie. I've added the following code to a controller on my dotnet core app:

```
var formatVersion = 3;
var protector = _dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware", "<my-app-name>", "v2");
var cookieValue = Request.Cookies["<my-app-name>"];
var cookieValueDecoded = Base64UrlTextEncoder.Decode(cookieValue);
var unprotectedBytes = protector.Unprotect(cookieValueDecoded);

using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(unprotectedBytes))
{
    using (GZipStream gzipStream = new GZipStream((Stream)memoryStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader((Stream) gzipStream))
        {
            if (reader.ReadInt32() != formatVersion) return (AuthenticationTicket) null;
            string authenticationType = reader.ReadString();

            string str1 = ReadWithDefault(reader, "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name");
            string roleType = ReadWithDefault(reader, "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role");
            int length = reader.ReadInt32();
            Claim[] claimArray = new Claim[length];
            for (int index = 0; index != length; ++index)
            {
                string type = ReadWithDefault(reader, str1);
                string str2 = reader.ReadString();
                string valueType = ReadWithDefault(reader, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string");
                string str3 = ReadWithDefault(reader, "LOCAL AUTHORITY");
                string originalIssuer = ReadWithDefault(reader, str3);
                claimArray[index] = new Claim(type, str2, valueType, str3, originalIssuer);
            }
            ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity((IEnumerable<Claim>)claimArray, authenticationType, str1, roleType);
        }
    }
}
```

Most of this code comes from `Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.Serializer.TicketSerializer` in `Microsoft.Owin.Security, Version=3.0.1`. It is therefore essentially a reversal of the protection logic that is used in the originating ASP.NET app, and it works fine. It ends with a `ClaimsIdentity` that matches the account which authenticated on the other app. This tells me that the cryptography config and keys are matched between the apps.

So there must be some other difference between the built-in code that unprotects the authentication cookie on both sides. But I'm unclear about how to diagnose where the difference is. My assumption is that I've missed something on the dotnet core side which makes the cookie authentication interoperable.

---

**UPDATE 2**

Having dug around a bit more I think this comes down to the data serializer format version. In my dotnet core app if I dig into the `TicketDataFormat` I see it uses `TicketSerializer.Default` which is an implementation of `IDataSerializer<AuthenticationTicket>` that has a hard-coded `FormatVersion` of `5`. There's also a comment at the top of `TicketSerializer` saying:

> This MUST be kept in sync with Microsoft.Owin.Security.Interop.AspNetTicketSerializer

However you can see in my UPDATE 1 above that when I ripped out some of the serialization logic from the ASP.NET web app, it is working with a format version of 3. Note that this app is using the version of `TicketDataFormat` that comes with `Microsoft.Owin.Security, Version=3.0.1.0` and that assembly has a `TicketSerializer` with hard-coded `FormatVersion` of `3`.

So, how can I keep ensure these serializers are compatible on both sides?

---

**UPDATE 3**

Realised I'm a total tool and was missing a key part of the Microsoft docs. Above I state this:

> I also assign the ticket data format using this data protector as per the docs: `new TicketDataFormat(dataProtector)`.

Well, actually I should have been using the `AspNetTicketDataFormat` type provided by the `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Interop` library. Having corrected this I can now obtain a claim principal in my dotnet core app using the following:

```
var dataProtector = _dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware", "<my-app-name>", "v2");

var ticketDataFormat = new TicketDataFormat(dataProtector);

var ticket = ticketDataFormat.Unprotect(cookieValue, "");
```

Here I can see `ticket.Principal.Identity` populated with my identity from the cookie.

However, I still can't get my app in an authenticated state. I'm clearly still not wiring up the cookie authentication middleware correctly. My `Startup` still just looks like the second code block in my original post. Feels like the final hurdle if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually by the time I reached Update 3 I had been working on this long enough that the session had expired but I was still using that session to test. So the reason my cookie was being rejected was due to session expiry, not some coding issue. I discovered this once I added trace-level logging to the app and there was the answer, staring at me from the console! Will leave this here in case the process described in the post benefits anyone else.