# Shared session cookie is not being recognised by authentication scheme

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, authentication, cookies

This follows on from a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66887511/unable-to-share-authentication-cookie-with-new-dotnet-core-web-app) which started as a general issue and is now more specific.

In short, I've been following guidance (such as [this from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#share-authentication-cookies-without-aspnet-core-identity), [this from Scott Hanselman](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/sharing-authorization-cookies-between-aspnet-4x-and-aspnet-core-10), and [this from Barry Dorrans](https://github.com/blowdart/idunno.CookieSharing?WT.mc_id=-blog-scottha)) to allow me to share the authentication cookie issued by a legacy ASP.NET web app with a new dotnet core app running on the same domain.

I'm confident that I'm using the recommended `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Interop` library correctly. On that side (the old ASP.NET app), the `CookieAuthenticationOptions` are configured with `AuthenticationType` and `CookieName` both set to the same value - `SiteIdentity`. This same value is also used in the interop data protector setup:

```
var appName = "SiteIdentity";

var encryptionSettings = new AuthenticatedEncryptorConfiguration
{
    EncryptionAlgorithm = EncryptionAlgorithm.AES_256_CBC,
    ValidationAlgorithm = ValidationAlgorithm.HMACSHA256
};

var interopProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(
    new DirectoryInfo(keyRingSharePath),
    builder =>
    {
        builder.SetApplicationName(appName);
        builder.SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(365 * 20));
        builder.UseCryptographicAlgorithms(encryptionSettings);

        if (!generateNewKey)
        {
            builder.DisableAutomaticKeyGeneration();
        }
    });

ShimmedDataProtector = new DataProtectorShim(
    interopProvider.CreateProtector(
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware",
        appName,
        "v2"));
```

I log in using this app, confirm I have a cookie named `SiteIdentity` then switch to a new dotnet core app running on the same domain.

There, without adding authentication middleware I can confirm that I can unprotect and deserialize the cookie. I do this by setting up data protection in `Startup` to match the other app:

```
var appName = "SiteIdentity";

services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(keyRingSharePath))
    .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(365 * 20))
    .DisableAutomaticKeyGeneration()
    .UseCryptographicAlgorithms(new AuthenticatedEncryptorConfiguration()
    {
        EncryptionAlgorithm = EncryptionAlgorithm.AES_256_CBC,
        ValidationAlgorithm = ValidationAlgorithm.HMACSHA256
    })
    .SetApplicationName(appName);
```

Then in my controller I can use a data protector to manually unprotect the cookie:

```
var appName = "SiteIdentity";

var protector = _dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector(
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware",
    appName,
    "v2");

var cookieValue = Request.Cookies[appName];
var format = new TicketDataFormat(protector);
var ticket = format.Unprotect(cookieValue);
```

I can confirm that `ticket.Principal` does indeed reference a claims principal representing the account which I signed in with on the other app.

However, I've found it impossible to wire up the cookie authentication middleware to properly protect my endpoints using this cookie. This is what I've added to `Startup`, after the data protection code above:

```
var protectionProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IDataProtectionProvider>();

var dataProtector = protectionProvider.CreateProtector(
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware",
    appName,
    "v2");

services
    .AddAuthentication(appName)
    .AddCookie(appName, options =>
    {
        options.TicketDataFormat = new TicketDataFormat(dataProtector);
        options.Cookie.Name = appName;
    });
```

By my understanding this is telling the middleware that I have an authentication scheme named "SiteIdentity" (the advice is that authentication scheme must match the ASP.NET authentication type) which expects a cookie also called "SiteIdentity" which will contain protected data that the supplied data protector can interpret.

But when I add the attribute `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "SiteIdentity")]` to my controller I'm kicked away to a login page.

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. As I've shown, I can confirm that it is indeed possible to use this data protector and ticket format to interpret the authentication cookie, so I guess I must have something wrong in this middleware wiring, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: `"SiteIdentity"` or `"Site.Identity"`? I see your `appName` is set to `SiteIdentity` at first, but later you use `"Site.Identity"` in the `AuthorizeAttribute`.

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo. I didn't want to use the real value to avoid revealing internals. Will correct.

Comment: the code you test manually may not be equivalent with the code inside the authentication middleware, here's where the ticket is read from cookies https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Security/Authentication/Cookies/src/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs#L135 - You may have to debug into the source code (there) to see what happens. It's hard for others to see what's wrong here (of course someone with depth knowledge about this may spot it).

Comment: Turns out I was being an idiot. The cookie I was testing with represented an expired session. Once I enabled tracing I could see this info in the console ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore. It turns out that my code is actually correct. I had been working on this solution for long enough that the session represented by the cookie value I was using to test had expireed. Will leave this question here in case the code benefits anyone trying to achieve the same.